# <Video> not playing on first load

Tags: css, html

I Created an HTML video for our site's header.
It works really well, but sometimes on mobile or first-time visitors, it stays at a black screen (similar to that of loading).

Sometimes 1 refresh fixes it, other times a few more are needed.

Do you have any suggestions to make this work more often than not?

Heres the code:

```
    <style>
    #myVideo {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100vw;
    object-fit: fill;
}

.overlay {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    opacity: .05;
}</style>
<body>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<!-- The video -->
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" preload="auto" id="myVideo">
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked DevTools Network for error loading video?

Comment: I used the Network tab in Chrome Developer to distinguish that the issue is with video loading.  It takes around ~30 seconds

Comment: It also looks like the video is loading while playing as well.  Could making the file size of this video less significantly help? It is around 68 MB's.

Comment: Is it meant to autoplay, or not?

Comment: Yes and it does.  The issue is with load times.

Im pretty new to using videos in these sort of environments.

Im currently using handbrake to shrink it but maybe there is other things I could do website-side wise.

Comment: How large is your video file? Your hosting service may be loading it slower than your browser loads the page.

Comment: I was looking into it, and its around 36mb.  

Pretty Huge, I've lowered it from a larger file, but the time was not affected

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `autoplay`, `load` and other Boolean attributes are being declared/undeclared in the wrong way. If you **do** want to have the video autoplaying, then you must do one of the following: `autoplay` by itself, or `autoplay="autoplay"`. Do this to all your Boolean attributes (`autoplay`, `muted`, `loop` and `playsinline`), and your video will work.

***ALSO***: If you **don't** want these actions to occur (you don't want it to automatically play, etc.) then get rid of the attribute entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

The issue I'm having is that the video isnt loading fast enough.  Autoplay, loop and other bool values all seem to work this way.  the WP environment does the ="" automatically

Comment: Ahh. Sorry about that.